# Is there an alternative to \b and/or negative lookahead for JFLEX?

Tags: java, regex, jflex, word-boundary

I am building a Scanner and can't seem to find a way to identify operators like "if" or "else" using JFlex & Regex. Since JFlex *doesn't fully conform* I can't use word-boundary or (?<=\s|^) + (?=\s|$) because neither ? or $ are allowed.
The idea is to find the correctly written operators not ifo or elso. Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Since JFlex doesn't fully conform" Conform to what?

Comment: The user manual states: "_The Standard Recommendation version of the Annex C Compatibility Properties are provided, with two exceptions: \X Extended Grapheme Clusters; and \b Default Word Boundaries_". That's what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The idea is to find the correctly written operators not ifo or elso. Thanks in advance.

Just use "if" and "else" and have another pattern that would match `ifo` and `elseo` (like for identifiers) and that comes after the patterns for `if` and `else`:

```
"if"                   { /* it's an if */ }
"else"                 { /* it's an else */ }
[a-zA-Z_][a-zA-Z_0-9]* { /* it's an identifier */ }
```

Following the maximal munch rule, this will match the identifier rule for inputs like `ifo` and `elseo` and will only match the "if" and "else" rules when there is no longer prefix of the input that would match the identifier rule.

If your language doesn't have identifiers and `ifo` and `elseo` are just supposed to be invalid tokens, you can keep the pattern and just change the action to treat it as an invalid token rather than an identifier.